# c#: Calling common method of stored references to class objects from object[] array

Tags: c#, class, methods

Is using a switch on object types really the main way of calling a common function of stored references to class objects? It doesn't have to be a 'object' value type.

```cs
using System;

public class MainClass { public void Main() { print "hello world"; } }
public class SubClassOne : MainClass { }
public class SubClassTwo : MainClass { }

public class Storer
{
     public void Main() {
         object[] objects = new object[2];
         objects[0] = new SubClassOne();
         objects[1] = new SubClassTwo();
         for(i=0;i<2;i++)
         {
             switch(objects[i].GetType().ToString())
             {
                 case: "SubClassOne":
                     SubClassOne subclass = objects[i];
                     subclass.Main();
                     break;
                 case: "SubClassTwo":
                     SubClassTwo subclass = objects[i];
                     subclass.Main(); //Could probably call after the switch
                     break;
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Note: Code not parsed, so there may be serious errors.

Comment: why not using `MainClass[] objects = new MainClass[2]` ?

Comment: Would I be able to add subclasses to it, when it really stores MainClass? Never tried.

Comment: `SubClassTwo` is extending `MainClass`, so you can use it as `MainClass` without casting. Using `objects[0].Main()` is valid

Comment: if i am getting the question right, why not to try this - objects[i].Main()
Can you explain why u require an switch?

Comment: "Using objects[0].Main() is valid"
Huh... I remember the builder saying the value type 'object' has no such method, so I added casting.

Comment: What you're saying is true; object has no such method. That's why you should define the method in MainClass and override in your subclasses. I fixed my answer with a complete example. Take a look and hopefully it is what you're looking for! :)

Comment: @doctorlove
I should have figured that this is possible. Because I was already adding derived classes of the 'object' value type to an 'object' array. Although I wrote my question a bit wrong, since the classes are not always derived from the same class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"[Stringly](http://neologisms.rice.edu/index.php?a=term&d=1&t=14876)" typed object oriented code is such a [bad idea](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html). You (almost) never need to know the type of an object via a string.

Changing your "print" to `Console.WriteLine` and main to this works fine

```
    MainClass[] stuff = new MainClass[2];
    stuff[0] = new SubClassOne();
    stuff[1] = new SubClassTwo();
    foreach(var item in stuff)
    {
        item.Main();
    }
```

If the problem is you are determined to use an array of `object`, AlexH has answered.

Answer (score 1):

In that case, I suggest to use [as keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to perform a safe cast operation :

```
using System;

public class MainClass { public void Main() { print "hello world"; } }
public class SubClassOne : MainClass { }
public class SubClassTwo : MainClass { }

public class Storer
{
    public void Main() {
     object[] objects = new object[2];
     objects[0] = new SubClassOne();
     objects[1] = new SubClassTwo();
     for(i=0;i<2;i++)
     {
        var myMainClass = objects[i] as MainClass;
        if (myMainClass != null)
        {
            myMainClass.Main();
        }
     }
 }
}
```

As wudzik said it should be even better to declare objects as a MainClass array

Comment: You're right, you can perform a direct as Operation and check if the result is null, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should implement a more object oriented solution. Instead of creating an array consisting of objects you should make MainClass abstract and define an abstract method Main. After that you should implement Main in you sublclasses.

In this way you can exchange your code to:

```
using System;

public abstract class MainClass { public abstract void Main(); }

public class SubClassOne : MainClass { 
    public override void Main() { print "SubClassOne, hello world"; } 
}
public class SubClassTwo : MainClass { 
    public override void Main() { print "SubClassTwo, hello world"; }
}

public class Storer
{
    public void Main() {
        MainClass[] objects = new MainClass[2];
        objects[0] = new SubClassOne();
        objects[1] = new SubClassTwo();

        foreach(MainClass mc in objects)
        {
            mc.Main();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of solving this in a nice way, depends on:

## If you know types and there are not too much of them:

Use LINQ `OfType<>()`. For more details see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx)

```
foreach (var item in objects.OfType<SubClassOne>())
{
   item.Main();
}

foreach (var item in objects.OfType<SubClassTwo>())
{
   item.Main();
}
```

## If there are many types, just introduce common interface

```
interface ISharedApi
{
    void Main();
}

class SubClassOne : ISharedApi
class SubClassTwo : ISharedApi
```

And implement this/mark each type by it, then you just need single loop:

```
var objects = new List<ISharedApi>();
objects.Add(new SubClassOne());
objects.Add(new SubClassTwo());

foreach (var item in objects)
{
   item.Main();
}
```